# Is there a better way I can apply the count function to two sets of lists?

Tags: python, list, loops, count, binary

I have two binary lists, is there a better way of assigning the binary list containing more 1's to the variable moreOnes? Bellow is my attempt.

```
    moreOnes = []
    for i in len(list1):
      if list1.count(1) > list2.count(1):
        moreOnes = list1
      else:
        moreOnes = list2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use max function with lambda expression as a key:

```
moreOnes = max(list1, list2, key=lambda x: x.count(1))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the list with more 1's, you don't need that loop, just the `if` statement inside. If you want it more succinct, you could also do:

```py
moreOnes = list1 if list1.count(1) > list2.count(1) else list2
```